# How to pass multiple objects to hook_view()?

Tags: views, 6, hooks

I want my `hook_view($node)` to display not only the `$node`, but other fancy stuff too - like a table on the bottom using a while-statement. How can I do this?

I am only able to pass one object to `hook_view()` so I am limited to one object for output? For example:

```
function Mymodule_load($node) {
  $sql = "SELECT colors FROM ctable,node WHERE ctable.nid=node.nid";
  //returns lots of color (e.g. blue, red, green, pink)
  $result = db_query($sql);
  //here's where I am stuck!
  while($row = db_fetch_object($result)) {
    return $row;  //oh noes! $row keeps getting overwritten
                  //and all my colors aren't being passed to hook_view
  }
}

function Mymodule_view($node,$teaser=false,$page=false) {
  node_prepare($node,$teaser);
  $node->content['colors'] = array(
    // only can display ONE color.
    '#value' => $node->colors
  )
  return $node;
}
```

The above code returns only ONE color whereas I want ALL my colors to be passed to `hook_view()`.

THE SOLUTION:

```
while($row = db_fetch_object($result)) {
  $colors[] = $row->colors;
}
$node->colors = $colors;
return $node;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`hook_load()` gives you the node that was just loaded. The reason it gives you the node is so that you can modify it. So you'd do something like $node->myModule['colors'] = array ( some colors here... ); Read up on the [API documentation](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.api.php/function/hook_load/7).

See also the [API docs](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.api.php/function/hook_view/7) for `hook_view()`.

If you move on to Drupal 7, you can do all this stuff as fields. :-)

Comment: THANK YOU!  I was able to solve this problem with your suggestion.  I will take a look into Drupal 7. Fortunately my project is still in the early stages of development.